# I try to use the POST method here and I get the 405 error, as I try to get information from an html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am providing the code down here, in case it helps somehow.I am creating a route called "clients" that will afterwards store the client's information when he presses "CONFIRM" on the page.I am using NodeJS and Express.I am new to back-end development and I am trying to figure out how to make things work.

Here is the code :

```
var mysql= require("mysql");
const express=require("express");
const app=new express();
const morgan=require("morgan");
app.use(morgan('short'));
app.use(express.static("registration.html"));

const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post('/clients',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("inserting..")
    console.log("first name: "+req.body.fullName)

})

var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"clientsDATABASE"
})

app.listen(3004,()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 3004");
})

con.connect(function(err){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("CONNECTED")

    con.query("select * from clientsVectra", function(err,result,fields){
        if (err) throw err
        console.log(result);
        app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
            res.send(result);
        })
    })
})
```

The page that sends the user's input data is a remote one.
Here is the html for that page :

```
<div class="container">
            <form action="/clients" method="POST">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="first-name" 
                name="firstName" placeholder="FULL NAME" autocomplete="off" 
                ng-class="{'has-error': registerMinimalForm.firstName.$invalid &amp;&amp; registerMinimalForm.$submitted}" ng-required="true" 
                ng-model="rmfc.model.firstName" required="required" name="fullName">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">

            <div class="card-body">
                <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="email" 
                name="firstName" placeholder="E-MAIL ADDRESS" autocomplete="off" 
                ng-class="{'has-error': registerMinimalForm.firstName.$invalid &amp;&amp; registerMinimalForm.$submitted}" ng-required="true" 
                ng-model="rmfc.model.firstName" required="required">
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="phonenum" 
                    name="firstName" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" autocomplete="off" 
                    ng-class="{'has-error': registerMinimalForm.firstName.$invalid &amp;&amp; registerMinimalForm.$submitted}" ng-required="true" 
                    ng-model="rmfc.model.phoneNumber" required="required">
                </div>   
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  role="button" id="b1j">CONFIRM!</a>
                      </div>        
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: 405 error means method not allowed, so for some reason that the browser does not like the POST method.

Comment: Where is the listener/code for the button when it is pressed?

Comment: @C2H50H then how do I get the user's input from the registration.html while using express and nodeJS?The listener is in another .js file and as I can see nodeJS doesn't recognise the 'document' variable when I use the document.getElementsByClassName("className")

Comment: I think you need to have something in your .js to handle the request, not positive though. Sorry don't know much about js.

Comment: your form says action="/clients", but I think that needs to point to a php page, like action="/clients/submitForm.php"